# Extract and log data sent through Bluetooth from external devices to an Android app

Tags: bluetooth, logging, data-monitoring

I would like to extract and log live data from an app ([SMART BMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inuker.bluetooth.daliy)) that I installed from the Play Store. The app monitors various live parameters of an electric drive train such as power and voltage. The app receives the data via Bluetooth.

Is there a way to scrape (or record) this live data from the app and log it as an Excel CSV file relative to time?

Comment: If the app doesn't provide such functionality (or at least output their log somewhere), then I'm afraid it'll be really difficult or almost impossible to do that.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thank you for your response. I'll have to go about it in a different way... Perhaps an arduino board with a sensor monitoring the data. This could link via bluetooth to my phone and use a data logging app such as the arduino science journal.

Comment: The app data is out of reach, you could only sniff the raw Bluetooth traffic and build your own app or a program on a PC: Android comes with a built-in Bluetooth "sniffer" for debugging purposes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877761